# Direct operations on off-heap arrays

Tags: java, scala, jvm

Recently I've been looking for a way to store large chunk of data in memory for scientific computing. I've looked at [scala-offheap](https://github.com/densh/scala-offheap) and [LArray](https://github.com/xerial/larray). One thing I noticed is that if I have an existing function operating on a native Java array, I cannot apply it directly on an off-heap array; both libraries require a copy from off-heap array to a normal one.

I don't know if this is a real limitation of the memory model, or simply a limitation imposed by the library APIs. Is it possible to get a Java array "view" of an off-heap array?

Comment: No that is not possible

Comment: “off-heap” and “Java array” are a contradiction, as the Java heap is, per definition, the memory area of all Java objects. Since this formal aspect has no immediate technical consequences, the question arises what you want to achieve with this self-contradicting wish. All you said so far, is, that you want to “store large chunk of data in memory”. What’s wrong with using the heap for that?

Answer (score 3):

[jillegal](https://github.com/serkan-ozal/jillegal) claims to be able to do that, but it's basically one big hack because it violates assumptions of the garbage collectors and it is relying on particular collectors not going up in fire when they encounter those violations. It's probably not a good idea for production use.

If you only need to access primitive types then bytebuffers currently are the abstraction that provides the same APIs for on-heap and off-heap access but you have to extract fields one by one.